# if @bean method return new Object, it cause memory leak?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have java code like this.

```
public class feignConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
        return new HeaderInterceptor();
    }
}
```

I know that Spring container holds all the beans and the scope of all the beans is "singleton" by default.

But the code looks like every time request intercepts, object creates.

So I should know whether it causes memory leak or something else.

Comment: Also in singleton you create new object, but once, as spring singleton, so what is the question?

Comment: Well, it depends a lot on the circumstances. Creating an object on every call isn't necessarily resulting in a memory leak - in fact many libraries do this, e.g. anytime you call math operations on `java.math.BigDecimal`. In Java memory leaks are typically called by live code holding onto objects that are no longer needed or that code being held alive unnecessarily (i.e. accessible by a live thread). If you use Spring as it is intended and don't interfere with its thread handling etc. you very likely won't get any memory leaks.

Comment: @user7294900
Thanks for quick comment.

I was thinking Bean method is on memory once, but there is "new" keyword which mean creating new object every time ( allocating memory ). so i was wondering "new" keyword cause  memory leak or not.

Comment: since it's created as singleton by default, it only recreate if its instance doesn't exist or has been garbage collected.

Comment: Spring will call the requestInterceptor() method only once to create the bean, not for every request.

Comment: In Java, you don't get a memory leak from simply creating or returning an object.  No matter how often you do it.  The GC will deal with that.  Problems arise if something keeps a reference to the object so that it never becomes *unreachable*.   And even then, it is only a *problem*  if the number or size of the objects that are leaked is unbounded.